# Spring Injection failing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this code:

```
    private ServiceLayer serviceLayer;  
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/process" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String processMessaging(HttpServletRequest request) 
    {
        return serviceLayer.getMd5Hash();

    }
```

**Service layer**

```
@Autowired
    public ServiceLayer() {
    }
```

The problem is that when I run the project, the `Md5Hash` is null as well as `serviceLayer` instance is also null, it seems like Constructor is not being called.

When I use the following code instead then it works fine:

```
@Autowired
    private ServiceLayer serviceLayer;
```

ServiceLayer is annotated with `@Component.`

Then instance of `serviceLayer` is not null but `md5Hash` is null. I have recently learned concept of `Spring Injections` but it is not working as expected. Someone please tell what should I do?

**Edited**

it runs when i make Property Autowired instead of constructor. but  why it is not working with Constructor being Autowired with or without init() method.

I tried making md5Hash method as Bean as "Link" suggested but that throws me into another error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.orange.raidar.backend.controller.raidarDummyController.md5Hash; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getMD5hash' defined in class path resource [com/orange/raidar/backend/filter/ServiceLayer.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.String]: Factory method 'getMD5hash' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
```

what i tried now :

```
@Bean
    public String mD5Hash() {
        md5Hash = MD5Generator.getMd5HashCode(httpRequestToString());
        return md5Hash;

    }
```

and in controller

```
@Autowired
    private String md5Hash;
```

Comment: In your class ServiceLayer what is the init value for your property Md5Hash?

Comment: It is a bad practice to make service layer dependent on your `HttpServletRequest` object

Comment: The second way to declare your ServiceLayer is the right one.

Comment: This means that the method getMd5Hash() returns null so it is working. You need to check that method.

Comment: init just calling method which sets  md5Hash

Comment: @khanou : whats wrong with first method?  cant we make constructor autowired ?

Comment: Can you post the defination of `getMd5Hash()`

Comment: @Tajinder i am not able to get your question or might be i am seeing something very obvious . please can let me know if your issue is resolved or not , if not please metion clearly what you want? mentioned above is vague

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialized Md5Hash inside init() might be going out of scope. A better strategy would be to have something like this

```
@Component
public class ServiceLayer() {

    @Autowired
    private String md5Hash;

    // Some other code
}
```

and then declare a bean by

```
@Bean
public String md5Hash() {
    // Some code
    return md5HashString;
}
```

declared in some `@Config` file

Comment: Service layer is @Component
public class ServiceLayer {

Comment: yes ,i tried but still its not working. i am editing my code so that it can be seen clearly.

Comment: Well you are right,it went out of scope. now i tried just with blank constructor but still its not working. but when i try @Autowired on Servicelayer serviceLayer then it works.

Comment: i dont know ,if i understood you right , but i tried making it Bean like this    @Bean
 public String getMD5hash() {
  md5Hash = MD5Generator.getMd5HashCode(httpRequestToString());
  return md5Hash;

 }          and  Autowired
 private String md5Hash;     but it gives error while running code    
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getMD5hash' defined in class path resource and another error is Could not Autowire field md5Hash

Comment: The naming matters. Make sure the property name is the same as the method name. Try using Md5Hash instead of getMD5hash. Otherwise, name it using @Bean("md5Hash")

Comment: yes you are right ,http request is not there when it tries to initialise bean so   probably that is the reason. And any suggestions why Constructor autowired is not working with or without init() method ?

Comment: Constructor with an @Autowired means you want DI on the parameters, so that would be asking for an HttpServletRequest bean. I don't think the init method makes use of this object. The init method might be initializing a new string inside itself which goes out of scope upon completion. I'm already speculating here based on information given, can't tell exactly what the problem unless I see the entirety of it.

Comment: ok thanks buddy. you helped me in understanding the concept.:)

Answer (score 1):

I think that when you use @Autowired this is not call your constructor with HttpServletRequest in param.

It's call the default constructor. You can use @PostConstruct annotation on your init methods.

```
@Component
public class ServiceLayer {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
      // set your md5
    }
  ...
}
```

Into your controller just keep

```
@Autowired
private ServiceLayer serviceLayer;
```

This will create and init your ServiceLayer and your controller will use the bean ServiceLayer into your controller

Comment: you mean just @Post init();  ?